# Trying to find every combination possible for a partially known string

Tags: python, combinations

Im trying to write a code that would find every single combination possible using numbers and letters for a partially know string. So for example a string "a***2l". I want it to replace the stars with every possible letter/number, however the length of the string must stay the same. Maybe it is possible to achieve using the 'itertools' library? It seems really difficult for me to understand how it would work. Any help appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: any example for your requirement

Comment: the `*` are not necessarily consecutive, right? it could be e.g. `"a*b**c*d*"`?

Comment: what Alex Hall did is exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import string
import itertools

for tup in itertools.product(string.ascii_letters + string.digits, repeat=3):
    print("a" + "".join(tup) + "2l")
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for.